# How to preserve type information when transforming AST to Graph (eDSL)

Tags: haskell, dsl

I'm trying to create a simple embedded DSL, which should allow
recursive definitions. To this end, I'm using [data-reify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify)
to convert the AST of an expression into a graph.

In the following example code, `Signal` represents the AST the user
can use (see the `test` signal). It is statically typed, so it isn't
possible to add a `Signal Double` and a `Signal Int`, for example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies #-}
import Control.Applicative hiding (Const)
import Data.Reify

data Value = VFloat64 Double
           | VFloat32 Float 
  deriving (Show)

class HasValue a where
    value :: a -> Value

instance HasValue Double where
    value x = VFloat64 x

instance HasValue Float where
    value x = VFloat32 x

data Signal t where
    Add :: Num t => Signal t -> Signal t -> Signal t
    Delay :: HasValue t => t -> Signal t -> Signal t
    Const :: HasValue t => t -> Signal t

data Node s where
    NodeAdd :: s -> s -> Node s
    NodeDelay :: Value -> s -> Node s
    NodeConst :: Value -> Node s
  deriving (Show)

instance MuRef (Signal t) where
    type DeRef (Signal t) = Node
    mapDeRef f (Add a b) = NodeAdd <$> f a <*> f b
    mapDeRef f (Const x) = pure $ NodeConst (value x)
    mapDeRef f (Delay x a) = NodeDelay (value x) <$> f a

test :: Signal Double
test = Add (Const 1.0) test
```

To evaluate the DSL, the AST is first converted into the `Node` type
using `reifyGraph` from `data-reify`. In the current formulation,
this involves using the `HasValue` typeclass, to convert the values
of each signal to the sum type `Value`. Unfortunately, this makes the `Node` graph
effectively dynamically typed, because to evaluate `NodeAdd`, I'll always
have to check if the two arguments use the same constructor.

So my question is: Is it possible to preserve the type information, which
was still available in the `Signal` AST, when converting to the `Node`
graph?

I already tried to parameterize `Node` with an additional type (i.e. `Node s a`),
but this didn't work out, because `DeRef (Signal t)` needs to be of kind `* -> *`.

Comment: Can you include evaluation part of the code (at least types)? Also, have you tried `Node a s` instead of `Node s a`, does that solve the problem with `Deref (Signal t)` kind?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-treify

Comment: Thanks, this package looks quite interesing. Unfortunately the documentation is a bit sparse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a type class, why not tag your value with a type using GADTs as you've done elsewhere?

```
data Value v where 
  VFloat64 :: Double -> Value Double
  VFloat32 :: Float  -> Value Float 

deriving instance Show (Value v)
```

Having `Num t` in the add constructor is now pointless - you now know that `t` can only ever be `Float` or `Double`.

```
data Signal t where
    Add :: Signal t -> Signal t -> Signal t
    Delay :: Value t -> Signal t -> Signal t
    Const :: Value t -> Signal t
```

Now, instead of throwing away your tags, `Node` keeps them:

```
data Node t s
    = NodeAdd s s 
    | NodeDelay (Value t) s 
    | NodeConst (Value t)
  deriving Show
```

Now there is no need for `value`, since your AST contains the `Value` datatype already:

```
instance MuRef (Signal t) where
    type DeRef (Signal t) = Node t
    mapDeRef f (Add a b) = NodeAdd <$> f a <*> f b
    mapDeRef _ (Const x) = pure $ NodeConst x
    mapDeRef f (Delay x a) = NodeDelay x <$> f a
```

In your example, the type of `test` was `(Fractional t, HasValue t) => Signal t`. Now, `t` is fixed by the constructor, and the correct type can be inferred:

```
let test = Add (Const (VFloat64 1.0)) test

> :t reifyGraph test
  reifyGraph test :: IO (Graph (DeRef (Signal Double)))
```

Comment: Sorry, for not answering. I couldn't login over the weekend. Your solution answers the question, so I'll accept it.